# SMTP Configuration of Swiftmailer Symfony2, Servage

Tags: smtp, symfony, swiftmailer

Please i want to know how to configure the SMTP for Swiftmailer in Symfony2.

I use FOSUserBundle, and i enabled the activation by email after registration, but after registration i get the message that says the activation email has been sent, without receiving any mail.

i use Servage.net hosting, and i have tried this configuration :

```
app/config/config.yml
        # Swiftmailer Configuration
    swiftmailer:
        transport: smtp
        host:      smtp1.servage.net
        auth_mode: login
        username: webmaster@myEmailAtServage.com
        password: mypassword
        port : 25
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try smtp2 with ssl/tls

From the servage wiki: https://www.servage.net/wiki/SMTP_server

```
The mail server smtp2.servage.net has support for TLS and SSL, using standard SSL port 465
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, now the Swiftmailer works with this configuration:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    port : %mailer_port%
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
```

parameters.ini

```
mailer_transport="smtp"
    mailer_host="smtp2.servage.net"
    mailer_user="me@mywebsite.com"
    mailer_password="myPassword"
    mailer_port=465
```